# Setup Google Sign in and get user data

Tags: php, oauth

I am new to this. So, need help from you guys.

I have two objectives.

1) I need to setup a "Sign In with Google Account" button on my website.

2) After visitor signs in I want to get profile information of the signed in visitor.

I hope you guys can guide me in the right direction. I am trying to do this in PHP.

Regards!

Comment: This Page will Probably Help [Google Buttons Policy](https://developers.google.com/+/plugins/buttons-policy)

Answer (score 0):

Try this tutorial on how to login to Youtube: http://www.conseo.cc/web-programming/477-youtube-oauth . Just change the scope variable to whatever you need and that's it.